# How to skip one textbox, which checking value of checkbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with multiple textbox, combobox, checkbox, etc.
I have written a code to check if value is null for controls - textbox & combobox - than end sub

```
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim msg1 As String
Dim msg2 As String
Dim msg As String

With Me
For Each ctrl In NewJoinerEntry.Controls

    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            If ctrl.Text = "" Then msg1 = "TextBox"
        Case "ComboBox"
            If ctrl.ListIndex = -1 Then msg2 = "ComboBox"
        Case Else
    End Select

Next ctrl
msg = "Please enter complete details in " & msg1 & " & " & msg2 & "."

If msg = "" Then
    .Hide ' hide the userform only if no empty textboxes and/or comboboxes
Else
    MsgBox msg
    Exit Sub
End If
End With
```

The above code is working fine but - **there is one text box** in the userform which gets activated only if a checkbox value is yes.

The above code is asking a values to be entered for that text box too. Want to eliminate that textbox from the loop which is checking for blank values.

Comment: You can't eliminate it from the loop, but you could check against its other properties i.e., is it `Visible` or `Enabled`?

Comment: I know it a very weird (& dumb too may be) question that i have. My textbox is enabled only if the checkbox value is true. See below code :    
    Private Sub CheckBoxPF_Click()
    If CheckBoxPF.Value = True Then
       TxtPFNum.Enabled = True
       TxtPFNum.BackColor = vbWhite

    Else:   TxtPFNum.Enabled = False
        TxtPFNum.BackColor = vb3DLight
End If
End Sub

Comment: Though my textbox is enabled only when the checkbox value is true, the loop for checking values in control - considers the disabled textbox and asks for a value

Comment: Don't put extended code snippets in comments, as you can see they will not be formatted properly and are (nearly) impossible to read that way. If you need to add code, revise your question and include the additional detail as needed. (the CheckBoxPF_Click routine code will not assist in answering this question, however).

Comment: Do you not understand my suggestion? In your control flow statements, simply add more logic to ignore the control if it is not enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore controls that are not `.Enabled`:

```
For Each ctrl In NewJoinerEntry.Controls

    If ctrl.Enabled Then
        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
            Case "TextBox"
                If ctrl.Text = "" Then msg1 = "TextBox"
            Case "ComboBox"
                If ctrl.ListIndex = -1 Then msg2 = "ComboBox"
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If
Next ctrl
```

By adding the `If ctrl.Enabled` logic inside the `For Each` loop, we've simply instructed the code to bypass/ignore any control which is not `Enabled=True`. Fine-tune or modify as needed.

You probably should modify also as below:

```
msg =  msg1 & " & " & msg2 

If msg = "" Then
    .Hide ' hide the userform only if no empty textboxes and/or comboboxes
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter complete details in " & msg & "."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: WOW.. Works like a treat. Thanks a lot. I'm not a full time on vba, more of a excel reporting person so please help me out with one more question - The first time i clicked the cmdsubmitdata button it showed me the prompts for no value entered & even ignored the disabled textbox. But once the form got submitted while second entry using the form it didnt give any prompts of blanks values :(

Comment: This condition is literally never true: `If msg = "" Then...` because you've immediately assigned `msg = "Please enter complete details in " + ...`. I am not sure I understand your follow-up question, but that probably has soemthing to do with it.

Comment: My follow up question is that the first attempt to enter values using the form got me the prompts of empty textbox & showed the "Please enter complete details in " + ... msg but the second attempt using the form did not get prompts and didnot get the msg of "Please enter complete details in " + ... It excepted blank values and pasted in my excel database